# add EditText successively clicking on checkBox

Tags: android

I have a question:
I would like to create an activity where the user can send SMS. The user have to provide recipient number and the content of SMS. Then, i will add a checkbox and if the user click on this checkbox, i would like to add an EditText "add more recipient" where the user have to provide an extra recipient number. Anyone has an idea about how to do this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to put a LinearLayout in your layout and set its orientation to vertical. Then (from your code) you can fill this linear layout with EditTexts or other Views.
You should perform all of this in a listener of the checkbox.
I hope this little answer will help.